# if..else if..else expression for non nullable reference types

Tags: c#, if-statement, instantiation, nullable-reference-types

I am curious how one would create a simple non nullable reference type in cases where assignment depends on an if..else if...else expression. Ternary operators work great for simple if...else cases, the new C#8 switch syntax works great for constants but what about run time?

For example, Kotlin provides something like this:

```
fun Test(value: Int) : String {
  val num: Int = Random.nextInt(0, 100)
  val message: String = if (value > num) { //message cannot be null here
    "greater than"
  } else if(value < num) {
    "less than"
  } else {
    "equal to"
  }
  return message
}
```

So with a C# non nullable reference type, how could I do the same thing? Would I have to build a factory to instantiate this non nullable string? Or use a dummy value initially for an if..else if..else block?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with kotlin syntax, what part of that code deals with (non-)nullability? Are you perhaps asking about the new switch expression?

Comment: And your question about "what about run time", are you sure the syntax in kotlin is any more optimal than just a regular set of if-statements?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Providing Kotlin syntax to C# programmers isn't helping much. C# `switch` statements do not require constant-valued expressions now; have you really looked closely at the newer `switch` constructions available? Please explain exactly what it is you're hoping to do, in a clearer, more detailed way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to initialize a variable, as long it is [definitely assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment). I.e. this is legal

```
string Test(bool b){
    string result;
    if(b){ result = "true"}
    else { result = "false"}
    return result;
}
```